# Anyone know why I'm getting an undefined index error with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

So, I'm new to using PHP but want to add whatever a user enters into this form into a database.

However, I'm getting an error for each index of name, role, and wage. It seems that it isn't picking that up.

HTML:

```
<form id="input" name="input" action="employees.php" method="post">
    <div id="boxes">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Input" class="name" required><br/>
        <input type="text" name="role" placeholder="Role" class="role" required><br/>
        <input type="number" step="any" name="wage" placeholder="Wage" class="wage" required>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onsubmit="return ajaxFunction()" class="button">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="button">Reset</button>            
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "employees";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully<br/>";

$name2 = $_POST['name'];
$role2 = $_POST['role'];
$wage2 = $_POST['wage'];

if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO employees VALUES ('$name2', '$role2', '$wage2')"))
    echo "Successfully inserted";
else
    echo "Insertion failed";

$conn->close();

?>
```

I also have some javascript set up to catch the values of each field and to send them to the PHP file. I'm probably doing something very wrong... but anyway here's the JS:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    var name = $('.name').val();
    var role = $('.role').val();
    var wage = $('.wage').val();
    var dataString = '&name1' + name + '&role1' + role + '&wage1' + wage;
    $.post('employees.php', {name1:name, role1:role, wage1:wage},    function(data){
        $('#main').html(data);
    });

    if (name == '' || role == '' || wage == '') {
        alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "employees.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use Isset function to check data is present or not in POST

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax `dataString` is

```
var dataString = '&name1' + name + '&role1' + role + '&wage1' + wage;
```

But in your PHP

```
$name2 = $_POST['name'];
$role2 = $_POST['role'];
$wage2 = $_POST['wage'];
```

Should be

```
$name2 = $_POST['name1'];
$role2 = $_POST['role1'];
$wage2 = $_POST['wage1'];
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure where it was getting the values from.

Answer (score 0):

The undefined error means that your data is not found, this is happening because your php is looking for a POST index of "name" whereas javascript is sending "name1".

There are a few issues with the setup that can be greatly improved here.

Firstly the onsubmit needs moved into the form tag.

```
<form onsubmit="return isFormValid()" id="input" name="input" action="employees.php" method="post">
```

Secondly you don't actually need to actually make an ajax request from Javascript because the return on submit is saying if the returned value of the js function is true submit the form otherwise don't. Therefore we just need to return a true or false based on form validation.

Here is the updated JS function.

```js
function isFormValid(){
  var name = $('.name').val(), 
      role = $('.role').val(), 
      wage = $('.wage').val(),
      data = [name, role, wage],
      isValid = true;

  data.forEach(function(el){
    if( isValid && !el.trim() ){
      alert("Please fill in all fields.");
      isValid = false;
    }
  });

  return isValid;
}
```

There are also some security concerns regarding MySQL injection from how the form data is being entered into the database without being escaped.

A quick solution is to add a basic PHP method to escape the strings before hitting the database.

```
// add at the top of your php file
function escape($value){ 
  return mysql_real_escape_string($value); 
}

// then update your variables
$name2 = escape($_POST['name']);
$role2 = escape($_POST['role']);
$wage2 = escape($_POST['wage']);
```

You can read more about mysql injection and how to prevent it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

EDIT ---------------------------

I've simplified the JS and removed the token issue you were having. If you add more input fields you can simply add a new variable to store it's value and add that variable name to the data array.

I've also updated the function name in both the JS and the html as it relates more to the purpose of the task.

Here is a working example:
http://codepen.io/davidbattersby/pen/LVabQe

obviously the php file doesn't exist so will point to a blank page if submission passes validation, it will alert and not send if invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the deep insight into my code. I really appreciate it! Do you know why I get "SyntaxError: unexpected token C" after submitting the form?

Comment: @Awbelton I've fixed the token issue now and updated the answer. I've actually simplified the JS further and now it's more maintainable if you add more fields in the future :)